# search string with find() method and returning every char after 2nd occurrence in string

Tags: python, string, find, indices, edx

**Here goes another edX exercise I got stuck earlier:**

They asked me to create a function called "after_second" that accepts two 
arguments: 
1. a string to search
2. a search term.

Function: **return everything in the first string after 
the SECOND occurrence of the search term.**

For example:
  **after_second("1122334455321", "3") -> 4455321**

The search term "3" appears at indices 4 and 5. So, this returns everything from the index 6 to the end.

after_second("heyyoheyhi!", "hey") -> hi!

The search term "hey" appears at indices 0 and 5. The search term itself is three characters. So, this returns everything from the index 8 to the end.

This is my code:

```
def after_second(searchString, searchTerm):
    finder = searchString.find(searchTerm)
    count = 0
    while not finder == -1:
        finder = searchString.find(searchTerm, finder + 1)
        count += 1
        if count == 1:
            return searchString[finder + len(searchTerm):]

print(after_second("1122334455321", "3")) #Sample problems by edX
print(after_second("heyyoheyhi!", "hey")) #Sample problems by edX
```

Which returns the expected correct answers:

```
4455321
hi!
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to structure the code I made. It outputs the correct answer but I'm not convinced it is the best answer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CoryKramer Should I join that forum or are you tagging someone?

Comment: See the help topic for [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Since you have working code, and are asking for potential improvements, that is a more appropriate question to ask on the Code Review site.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use `str.split` by passing the `maxsplit` parameter as 2, then taking the final item from the *split*:

```
>>> "1122334455321".split('3', 2)[-1]
'4455321'
>>> "heyyoheyhi!".split('hey', 2)[-1]
'hi!'
```

---

And your function can now be written as:

```
def after_second(search_string, search_term):
    return search_string.split(search_term, 2)[-1]
```